# How do I define and initialize an array of strings inside of a structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure

This is my code:

```
typedef struct mobiltelefon {

char herstellername[HLEN];
double displaydiagonale;
aufloesung_t aufloesung;

char standards[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][STRINGLENGTH+1] = {"GPRS", "EDGE", "HSDPA", "HSUPA","HSPA","LTE"};

}handy_t;
```

I keep getting this error:

```
expected ; at the end of declaration list
```

Comment: Please do not re-post essentially the same question, even when you are not satisfied with the answer that you get: usually, it will be promptly closed as a duplicate of your own question.

Comment: Someone recommended me to ask a new questions as I didn't provide enough information in the other question at first